# Word for the analog in another language

Tags: vocabulary, translation

There is a word that means the direct analog for a word in one language in another language. So, for example, the direct analog for `mizu` (water in Japanese) is `water` in English. I can't seem to remember what this word was.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117711/discussion-on-question-by-mrz-word-for-the-analog-in-another-language).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word I was looking for was 'cognate'. Thanks to Edwin Ashworth